# How can I merge iTunes libraries while keeping metadata?

Tags: itunes, metadata, macos

A tale of my iTunes libraries:

1. Getting songs on the iTunes store on my mid-2002 eMac (Mac OS X 10.1 Cheetah installed, 10.2 Jaguar updater thrown in the box)
2. Updated to 10.3 Panther, then 10.4 Tiger onto a new boot disk. Meant to transfer old songs over, but forgot and now have two iTunes libraries.
3. Mac got too old & slow to use, switched to my sister's old Vista-era laptop. Upgraded it to Windows 8(.1) first. Now have a third iTunes library.
4. Got a mid-2013 MacBook Air on Black Friday.  Gave in and downloaded 4 songs on it so far.  (Four iTunes libraries total to merge.)

I finally want to put all the old songs onto my iTunes library on the Air.  But unlike the various official iTunes backup routines, I want to preserve the play counts & last played (& other metadata) of the old songs.  In previous searches, I've found various shareware that may do the job, but I'm wondering if any script-kiddie or such has ever come up for a free solution?  If not, then what are the best pay-ware options?

Comment: oh yes that sounds like fun, I will think about it, but here are some main Ideas : Using rsync in terminal to actually "sync" the files | write the metadata of all iTunes isntances into the grouping tag via AppleScript | move all files to a new library and move the infos from the grouping tag back to the Library via AppleScript

Comment: This is the disadvantage of proprietary binary file formats.  Good luck.

Comment: If I get an answer to my related question it may be useful for you as well: http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/257689/151730